# Sonata Admin Bundle Search: NonUniqueResultException as Result

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

When I try to use the search-function in the Sonata Admin Bundle I always get:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template  ("The
>   query returned a row containing multiple columns. Change the query or
>   use a different result function like getScalarResult().") in
>   SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig at line 53.
>
> NonUniqueResultException: The query returned a row containing multiple
>   columns. Change the query or use a different result function like
>   getScalarResult().

When I do the search in the productive environment I just get a result if the Admin-Class has no result:

> e.g. for Countries (CountryAdmin Class): no result found

I am using sonata-project/admin-bundle (2.3.10)

I tried to reduce my admin-classes to a single one which is very basic - but still having this problems. Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with getScalarResult() method, when i did groupBy into my Admin class in createQuery() method.
Maybe it will help

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-users/cBT09egDtuo

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/297